# How to set explicit variables in an URL - python

Tags: python

In the following code snippet at the bottom, how do I explicitly set {0} and {1} to variables like:

0=host-123
1=128.24.22.21

such that I can keep the URL with the variables and call those variables elsewhere without actually explicitly setting them as host-123 and 128.24.22.21 elsewhere ?

```
def getipam(host, neighboraddr, token):
    """Fetch IPAM data for host and neighbor ip"""
    url = 'https://ipam.app.secretcdn.net/v1/hosts/{0}/bgp/neighbors/neighbor/{1}'.format(host, neighboraddr)
    response = requests.get(url, headers={'x-api-rw': token})
    results = response.json()
    return results
```

Comment: Do you want to save the contents of `url` somewhere? There are many ways to do that, e.g. by returning it.

Answer (score 0):

0/1/integers are immutable in python. You cannot change the value. You might want to call it by some other name like x or y something and then you can assign it